# Windows 10 Internet connection security problems

Tags: networking, browser, windows-10, internet-security

I recently bought a stationary PC with Windows 8.1 pre installed and instantly upgraded to Windows 10. The installation was error free and all apps works fine but the internet connection seems to be 100% unsecure!

I am unable to search for updates because I cannot connect to Microsoft's servers. 98% of all websites I visit gives me "security certification error" and on some websites I am unable to proceed to the website because there is no button to continue! This is on IE 8, Chrome & Edge.

On my internet connection this is only a problem on the new Windows 10 computer -- no other phone or laptop gives this error. I've tried reinstalling Windows 10, resetting the internet connection, resetting the settings to default on the computer and on all the browsers.

This error is not with every webpages though. Websites like Google, duckduckgo, youtube, facebook do not work but Bing and msn and every website that is connected in some way to the default websites works fine. 4chan is no problem either, no error, it seems to be inconsistent and doesn't really show any kind of pattern.

I'll provide computer specs or other info upon request.

Comment: If you run the command `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable` at a command prompt, do you see `0x0` or `0x1` as the value for ProxyEnable? A zero at the end indicates browsers aren't using a proxy server, whereas a 1 indicates they should use a proxy server. Are you using HTTP rather than HTTPS when visiting 4chan?

Comment: Check your clock date and time and timezone.  I have seen this, where the date will, for whatever reason, jump to the future or past and then the certificates will be invalid.  Sometimes, its the bios battery is dead/weak.